# Select >|< from string between quotes

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string like this: `*ngIf="thisThing > 0"`

Using RegEx, I'd like to select/return ONLY the `>` or in some cases, `<`.

I have the following expression: `(?<=")(?:.*?)(<|>)(?:.*?)(?=")` but this still selects everything inside the quotes. I only want to match that `>`.

I've been testing it here: https://regex101.com/r/4KPfbT/1

Comment: [*Some people, when confronted with a problem, think “I know, I'll use regular expressions.”  Now they have two problems.* - Jamie Zawinski](http://regex.info/blog/2006-09-15/247) Your question is an [X/Y Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Tell us what problem you are trying to solve instead of asking for help with the solution, which does not appear to be the correct approach.

Comment: It looks so wrong. Why do you need it?

Comment: I really don't see why isn't clear what the OP's asking. It's a direct question. The OP wants a regex that makes the metioned selection. Strait to the point.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you're over-complexifying it. Why not this way:

```
\w*=".*([<>]).*"
```

It works, take a look:

```js
console.log('*ngIf="thisThing > 0"'.match(/w*=".*([<>]).*"/)[1])
console.log('whatever="otherThing < 999"'.match(/w*=".*([<>]).*"/)[1])
```